# Gradle doFirst not updating WAR file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In a gradle project, I'm trying to change properties file value before generating WAR in `build.gradle` as follows,

```
war {
    doFirst {
        def propertyFile = file "src/main/resources/properties/about/About.properties"
        def props = new Properties()
        propertyFile.withReader { props.load(it) }
        props.setProperty('releaseDate', new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
        propertyFile.withWriter { props.store(it, null) }
    } 
    rootSpec.exclude("**/test.jar")
}
```

But whenever I give `build`, it generates WAR with previous date time. Say, I'm giving first build at `11:30` and second build at `11:34`. The second built WAR contains time as `11:30` instead of `11:34`. My intention is to update date whenever WAR is built. Is this way right?

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your solution and tested it. For me it always updates the date in the properties file when i run `build` or just `war`. Be aware that i changed the path for test purposes. Here is the code:

```
war {
    doFirst {
        File propsFile = file "src/main/resources/about.properties"

        Properties props = new Properties()
        props.load(propsFile.newDataInputStream())
        props.setProperty('releaseDate', new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
        props.store(propsFile.newWriter(), null)
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the `releaseDate` of the about.properties is **not** included into  the current war you are currently building since resources for the war you are packing had been processed **before** you execute war.

If you want to include the about.properties file with the time of the current build into the war archive, you should create a custom task to update your properties file and hook the task to a point into the buildchain before resources are processed. I created a sample task for you:

```
task updateReleaseDate {
    doLast {
        File propsFile = file "src/main/resources/about.properties"

        Properties props = new Properties()
        props.load(propsFile.newDataInputStream())
        props.setProperty('releaseDate', new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
        props.store(propsFile.newWriter(), null)
    }
}

processResources.dependsOn updateReleaseDate
```

Without the custom task your buildchain looks like this. The properties are updated after the resources are processed by the processResources task and therefore **not** included in the current war: `compileJava->processResources->classes->war`

With the custom task your buildchain looks like this. The properties are updated **before** the resources are processed by the processResources task and therefore **included** in the current war: `compileJava->updateReleaseDate->processResources->classes->war`